# Convert list to dictionary of tuples based on column value

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, data-conversion

I'm trying to convert the following lists in Python:

```
headers = [ 'Col1','Col2','Col3','Col4' ]
data    = [[  '1','A','D','X']
           [  '2','A','D','X']  
           [  '3','A','C','X']  
           [  '1','B','F','X']
           [  '2','B','F','X'] ]
```

to a dictionary of tuples with the **Col2** used as the unique key so the output would like like below:

```
{ 
  'A': [( '1','D','X'),('2','D','X'),('3','C','X') ]
  'B': [( '1','F','X'),('2','F','X') ]
}
```

So far I've managed to transpose and zip it to a dictionary with columns as keys but I stucked there.

```
transpose_result = map(list, zip(*data))
data = dict(zip(headers, transpose_result))
```

Can you help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need `headers` for ? It doesn't appear on the output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Iterate the `data` list items, and build new dictionary with `row[1]` as a key and `row[:1] + row[2:]` for values (list items):

```
>>> data = [
...     ['1','A','D','X'],
...     ['2','A','D','X'],
...     ['3','A','C','X'],
...     ['1','B','F','X'],
...     ['2','B','F','X'],
... ]

>>> d = {}
>>> for row in data:
...     d.setdefault(row[1], []).append(row[:1] + row[2:])
... 
>>> d
{'B': [['1', 'F', 'X'], ['2', 'F', 'X']],
 'A': [['1', 'D', 'X'], ['2', 'D', 'X'], ['3', 'C', 'X']]}
```

[`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) is used to populate the dictionary with a empty list when there's no key in the dictionary, so the `list.append` call can be done safely.

---

If you use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), it could be simpler:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for row in data:
...     d[row[1]].append(row[:1] + row[2:])
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {
    'A': [['1', 'D', 'X'], ['2', 'D', 'X'], ['3', 'C', 'X']],
    'B': [['1', 'F', 'X'], ['2', 'F', 'X']]})
>>> dict(d)  # to convert it back to dict
{'A': [['1', 'D', 'X'], ['2', 'D', 'X'], ['3', 'C', 'X']],
 'B': [['1', 'F', 'X'], ['2', 'F', 'X']]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps..

```
data    = [[  '1','A','D','X'],
           [  '2','A','D','X'],
           [  '3','A','C','X'],
           [  '1','B','F','X'],
           [  '2','B','F','X'] ]

res = {}

for d in data:
   key = d[1]
   d.remove(key)
   if key in res.keys():
          res[key].append(d)
   else:
          res[key] = [d]
```